silence: Creating a WarningFilter-style InfoFilter
I'd like to \InfoFilter some \PackageInfo calls similar to how silence uses \WarningFilter for \PackageWarning. Since other calls should remain untouched, silencing all calls is not a solution for me.
I have tried to provide to adapt \PackageWarning to achieve this goal, but lack knowledge to reach it.
% mwe.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{hush}
%\usepackage{csquotes}
\WarningFilter{stackexchange}{hide me}
\InfoFilter{stackexchange}{hide me}
\PackageInfo{stackexchange}{hide me}
\PackageWarning{stackexchange}{hide me}
\begin{document}
Hush.
\end{document}

Yet, mwe.log contains Package stackexchange Info: hide me on input line 7..
Another indicator that something is wrong appears when loading, e.g., csquotes:
! Argument of \csq@noline has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.2484 ...oad configuration file 'csquotes.cfg'..}

% hush.sty (code copied from silence, replacing some Warning with Info)
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{hush}[2024/05/30 Silence PackageInfo]
\RequirePackage{silence}
\makeatletter

\newcount\sl@InfoNumber

\newtoks\sl@TempBOI
\newtoks\sl@BankOfInfos

\def\sl@InfoNames{}

\def\InfoFilter{%
  \global\advance\sl@InfoNumber1
  \@ifstar%
    {\expandafter\gdef\csname\the\sl@InfoNumber:InfoMode\endcsname{safe}%
    \sl@InfoFilter}%
    {\sl@InfoFilter}}

\def\sl@InfoFilter{%
  \@ifnextchar[%
  {\sl@@InfoFilter}%
  {\sl@@InfoFilter[sl@family]}}

\def\sl@@InfoFilter[#1]#2{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname #2@InfoFilter\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\xdef\csname #2@InfoFilter\endcsname{\the\sl@InfoNumber:sl@#1}%
  \else
    \expandafter\xdef\csname #2@InfoFilter\endcsname{%
      \csname #2@InfoFilter\endcsname,\the\sl@InfoNumber:sl@#1}%
  \fi
  \expandafter\ifx\csname #1:InfoState\endcsname\relax
    \sl@Add\sl@InfoNames[#1]%
  \fi
  \expandafter\ifx\csname #1:InfoState\endcsname\sl@active%
  \else
    \ifsl@Immediate%
      \expandafter\gdef\csname #1:InfoState\endcsname{active}%
    \else
      \expandafter\gdef\csname #1:InfoState\endcsname{inactive}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \begingroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname\the\sl@InfoNumber:InfoMode\endcsname\sl@safe%
    \makeatletter
  \else
    \catcode`\\12
  \fi
  \sl@AddToBankOfInfos}

\long\def\sl@AddToBankOfInfos#1{%
  \sl@TempBOI{#1}%
  \edef\sl@act{%
  \global\noexpand\sl@BankOfInfos{%
    \the\sl@BankOfInfos%
    (:sl@\the\sl@InfoNumber:)\the\sl@TempBOI(:sl@\the\sl@InfoNumber:)}}%
  \sl@act%
  \endgroup}

\ifsl@ShowWarnings
\else
\let\sl@PackageInfo\PackageInfo

\def\PackageInfo#1#2{%
  \def\sl@PackageName{#1}%
  \ifsl@NoLine%
    \sl@NoLinefalse%
  \else
    \sl@StoreMessage{#2}%
  \fi
  \sl@PackageInfo{#1}{#2}}

\def\PackageInfoNoLine#1#2{%
  \sl@StoreMessage{#2}%
  \sl@NoLinetrue%
  \PackageInfo{#1}{#2\@gobble}}
\fi

\makeatother
\endinput

